# Enter or Remove Tags on Text Area Using Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I'm using Flex, and I have a text area, and when I enter some text and hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> button on the keyboard, I want it to create some design with an `X` mark, exactly like the Stack Overflow tags section.

If I enter "Flex" and hit space or enter, it will add `Flex X`. Then if I click the cross mark (`X`), "Flex" will be removed from the tags text box.

[image: Example]

Please help me with how to do this type of text box or text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this isn't trivial. Here's the approach I used several years ago on an email client.

Create a custom "container" class that either extends a `Group` (Flex 4) or `UIComponent` (Flex 3). This container will have two types of child objects: a `TextInput` and another object that represents the tag or email address.

Initially the container only has one child, the `TextInput` which is sized to be 100% of the width of the container. The `TextInput` has a keyboard event listener to detect when the user presses <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to "commit" the address and convert it to the "tag" object.

When the text is "commited", you:

- remove the text that was entered into the text input.
- create the "tag" based on the text that was entered and add it to the container. When adding it to the container, you add it in front of the text input.
- resize the text input so that it now occupies the remaining width of the container. If there isn't enough room for the text input on the current row, you position the text input on the next row beneath and make it 100% width again.

The "tag" object has an event listener for the "x" icon, which when clicked causes the tag to be removed from the container.

In Flex 4 your container class can be a `Group` and all of the sizing/positioning of the child text input and tag objects can be done by a custom Spark layout. If you were doing this in Flex 3, the sizing/positioning logic would be part of the container's logic. In both cases, you should use the appropriate Flex life cycle methods to do the sizing/positioning of the container's child objects.

Comment: Thankyou for your replay ... Please provide any Example for this give more useful to me...

Comment: The layout that I mentioned is a classic "flow layout" - you can find some examples of doing that on google (search terms: "flex flow layout"). I wrote this code for a client a few years ago, I don't have the code anymore, it belongs to the client I worked for. As I mentioned this isn't something trivial that someone can post a simple example of :)

Comment: Thankyou sir... i find some example on google but it is quit difficult ..once check this http://flex-autocomplete.com/demo/#app=40da&b817-selectedIndex=0